# How to convert const Exiv2::Value to int

Tags: c++, metadata, exiv2

I'm using Exiv2 to take the metadata of photograph. I would like to use some value of these metadata. but I have no idea how to convert exiv2 value to int. here is my souse cord.

```
int metadetascanner(const char* img)
{
    try
    {
        Exiv2::Image::AutoPtr image = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(img);
        image->readMetadata();
        Exiv2::ExifData &exif = image->exifData();
        Exiv2::Exifdatum &rotation = exif["Exif.Image.Orientation"];

        if (exif.empty())
        {
            cerr << "no exif" << endl;
            return -1;
            }

        int a = rotation.value();

        return a;
    }

    catch (Exiv2::Error& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I just write "int a = rotation.value(); " but I know it can not be like this.

I will really appreciate you if you help me.

Comment: I've edited my answer below. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Exiv2 documentation](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html), the orientation tag is already a short, so your "int a = rotation.value();" idea is valid.

Edited: 
From [API documentation of ExifDatum](http://www.exiv2.org/doc/classExiv2_1_1Exifdatum.html)

```
int a = rotation.toLong();
```

The return value meaning you read [here](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html).

Please comment if there is any thing wrong. I have not use Exiv2 for years.

Comment: thank you for your reply. value means that it can give us values of metadata. in case of my program, I want to get an orientation value. this is the error cord "error: cannot convert ‘const Exiv2::Value’ to ‘int’ in initialization"

Comment: I will try at home and give you my trial. @yutamotomura